# How can I get a list of network adapters with Python, on all OS platforms?

Tags: python, macos, networking

How can I get a list of network adapters with Python, on all OS platforms? If doing this in a cross-platform way is not possible, how might I do this on OS X?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**netifaces**](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/netifaces/) seems to do the job on Mac **OS X**, Windows XP, Windows Vista, Linux and Solaris:

```
sudo easy_install netifaces
```

...and then...

```
>>> import netifaces
>>> netifaces.interfaces()
```

Comment: Double check whether IPv6 is supported on Windows, if you care about that case.  When I recently investigated this module, it wasn't.

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone It certainly is these days (as of version 0.7, where dropping support for Win2K and earlier allowed the use of some newer APIs that can cope with IPv6).